# UniRx: Subscribing to ReactiveProperty<float> condition

Tags: unity

I'm trying to track a cold source with a contiguous range, and every example I've seen involves discrete increments or events that are already handled, so I'm vague on how to apply it.

Here's what I have:

```
ReactiveProperty<float> CurrentAlpha = new ReactiveProperty<float>(msg.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer>().GetAlpha());
CurrentAlpha.Where(x => x <= 0.0f).Subscribe(x =>
{
    Debug.Log($"CurrentAlpha == {CurrentAlpha} Observed");
    img.transform.SetParent(null);
    Destroy(msg);
});
```

I verified the alpha value, but never received notice when it reached 0. What have I mistaken?

EDIT: Found that it's actually subscribing to the value returned, which will always be 1. The value it receives is outside managed code, so there's no object property to observe, and CanvasRenderer itself doesn't observe it.

Is it possible to observe a method's return value?